# VueJS / v-html shows empty page (Bokeh-html)

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, bokeh

I am new to VueJS and I am trying to display a local html-file inside of the Vue Application.

I fetch the html file with axios like following:

```
<template>
  <div>

    <h1>bla</h1>

    <div v-html="input"></div>    

  </div>
</template>


<script> 
import axios from 'axios'

export default { 

  data() { 
    return { 
      input: null,
      }
 }, 

 created() {
 this.loadFile()
 },

 methods: {
        loadFile() {
          axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "../../test.html"
          })
            .then(result => {
              this.input = result.data;
              console.log("Data: " + result.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error("error getting file: " + error);
            });
        },
      }
}

</script>
```

We generate the html-Files with Bokeh (interactive Charts). If I open the html Files in the Browser they are shown correctly. These files contain 
`<script type="text/javascript">` 
and `<script type="application/json">`.

I tried this with a simple "Hello World"-html Example and this works fine and gets displayed in Vue. But when I read the actual file, I just get an empty page. The `console.log(result.data)` shows me the correct and complete html Code but I don't get any errors, so I can't figure out the problem.

Does anyone know, what I have to adjust to make this work?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have to generate HTML output from Bokeh? Bokeh has Python APIs to generate a JSON representation and JS APIs to load it. That seems like it would be much cleaner. https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#json-items Otherwise, best guess is the CDN resources that the HTML file normally load first in the `head` are no longer loading in time. This would show up as errors in the JS console. You could try loading the CDN scripts manually in your page.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the statement `this.input = result.data` tries to parse `result.data` as json but it is not.
Send the json from the server and use it in your code properly.

Comment: As an aside, the OP could use Bokeh APIs that generate JSON instead of trying to embed entire HTML pages, that would be a cleaner approach. https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#json-items

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this inside of a `.vue` file or is all of this in a `.html` file. If in html you need to remember to set the `el` property on your Vue model to ensure it knows where to render. If this is a `.vue` there has to be a defined `template` for the same reason.

[Here is a fiddle with an example](https://jsfiddle.net/ofubzj3s/). Yes the site has issues rendering with correct layout, but it renders. This is an example for `<script>` tags in your html file or just a raw .js file. Looks like you were making a Vue component (`.vue`) but the premise is still the same as long as you define the template where the Vue code is to be rendered.

Edit:

What does your vue file look like? This is what I'm expecting.

```
<template id="foo">
     <div v-html="input"></div> 
</template>

<script>
export default {
    template:'#foo',
    data: { 
        input: null
    },
    created() {
        this.loadFile();
        },
    methods: {
        loadFile() {
            let _this = this;
            axios({
                method: "get",
                url: 'https://jsfiddle.net/',
            })
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                _this.input = result.data;
                console.log("Data: " + result.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("error getting file: " + error);
            });
        },
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: This is inside an .vue file which I access through a router. I have the code in the export default {} part, which should declare the component, right?
I tried your fiddle in my project but it gives me an error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'render' of undefined

Comment: Yes, I updated the question with the complete code. The code itself is working, as I can load simple html files with not much content. But the files with type"application/json" show me nothing. Any other idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: How are you expecting the json content to display? v-html is intended for html. With json I would have expected individual v-bind or {{ object.property }} for displaying json results.